# Controller / RestController from Spring Gradle library

Tags: java, spring, gradle, controller, autowired

I want to use a Controller from a Gradle Library that I wrote but it does not get Autowired in the application where I use the library.

It does work when I use `@Import(ControllerName.class)` on the ApplicationClass of the running application but then I would have to manually import every single class from the library

`@ComponentScan` doesn't work and from what I read it doesn't work with `@Controller` and `@RestController` anyway only with `@Bean`, `@Service` and `@Component`.

This is the controller-class in the library (I left out the business logic)

```
@Controller
public class FrontendController {


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm(){
        return "login";
    }

    //some other endpoints
}
```

And this is currently the applicationClass in my main application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.demo", "com.myapp.login-lib"})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine with component scanning, the fact that it doesn't work with you means it isn't covered by the packages in the component-scan annotation. However you left out the package name so no way to determine that. `@Controller` like `@Service` (and others) is just another `@Component` so it will be detected by a component-scan. Also why would you want to autowire a controller? It should listen to a URL.

Comment: I may have used the wrong word by saying "Autowire" -> what I mean is that I want spring to automatically instanciate the Controller which it didn't do. My mistake was that I needed to do the componentScan inside the library and not in the main application (see my response below)
Still thanks for your advice :)

Comment: Adding the same component-scan (or basePackage of `@SpringBootApplication`) should yield the same result. Or just place your `@SpringBootApplication` in the `com.myapp` package and you don't need to do anything. That is the main application NOT in your library (as that doesn't really make sense). Also make sure that you don't distribute/package your library as a Spring Boot application itself, as that won't work either.

Comment: My main application has the package "com.myapp.demo", my lib has the package "com.myapp.login-lib" -> Using @ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.myapp.login-lib}) on the ApplicationClass next to @SpringBootApplication did not work. Using it on the Configuration in the library did work. So I don't know how I could do it "in the main application NOT in your library" -> it didnt work there

Comment: I don't have a @SpringBootApplication-Annotation in my library. The class with \@ Controller does lie in the library however

Comment: You don't need the `@SpringBootApplication` in your library (it doesn't add anything). As stated place the application in a top-level package `com.myapp` and it will detect everything no need for additional classes. The component-scan should work as well (used the same in dozens of projects) so there must be something strange in your setup).

Comment: I DONT HAVE @SpringBootApplication in my library. AS I said the problem is that Spring WILL NOT detect \@Controller etc from libraries automatically. In the library a \@Configuration class is needed for that to work -> see my solutation below

Comment: Reading is an art. I nowhere said yo need `@SpringBootApplication` in your library. Also spring will detect it in your libraries as I have used that on numerous projects (as well as others have). So no you don't need an `@Configuration` class. The fact that it doesn't work, indicates something else is not working in your setup. So what you have as a solution is a workaround NOT a solution.

Comment: "I don't have a \@SpringBootApplication-Annotation in my library." -> "You don't need the \@SpringBootApplication in your library" ..... yeah, reading truly is an art ;)

Comment: P.S: what the libraries you are referring to are probably doing is defining a META-INF file so you don't need to use \@Import on your service. Under the hood it does exactly the same thing though so my solution with an @Configuration-file is not really a workaround but the normal way to do this

Comment: No they aren't (wrote those things myself and they are plain jar files, which are on the classpth) and no your solution isn't the normal way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my error. In my library I (obviously) don't need a Class with a public static void main but what I do need to correctly autowire stuff from my library is a class with @Configuration.

Since I also have repositories and entities I also need to define their packages within the library -> so I added a class to the library that looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.login-lib"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.myapp.login-lib"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.login-lib"})
public class BaseConfiguration {
}
```

Then in the application where I use the library I only needed to import that configuration:

```
import com.myapp.login-lib.BaseConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(BaseConfiguration.class)
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```